# Discord.py 2.0 - Getting context for a HybridCommand

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to write a slash command version of my help command, and I want to check if a user can run a command.
This is my code here:

```py
@app_commands.command(name="help")
async def help(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, input: str = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Test")

    cmd = self.bot.get_command(input)

    ctx: commands.Context = await self.bot.get_context(interaction)

    try:
        await cmd.can_run(ctx)
        embed.add_field(name="Usable by you:", value="Yes")
    except commands.CommandError as exc:
        embed.add_field(name="Usable by you:", value=f"No:\n{exc}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Now this works fine if I want to check for a normal command (`commands.Command`), however this does not work with Hybrid Commands (`commands.HybridCommand`). I read [the docs for `bot.get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_context#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context) where it says:
`In order for the custom context to be used inside an interaction-based context (such as HybridCommand) then this method must be overridden to return that class.`
However I am not sure what this means exactly. How do I override it and what class do I need to return?

For completions sake, here is the error I get when I try to use this on a HybridCommand:

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'help' raised an exception: AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Again, when I use this on a normal command it works fine.

I would greatly appreciate any pointer!

Edit: An example of what I mean:

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def test1(self, ctx):
        print("Test1")

    @commands.hybrid_command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def test2(self, ctx):
        print("Test 2")
```

If you input `/help test1`, it will work fine, but error out on `/help test2`. Without the permission check it seems to also work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Current Answer

This can be resolved by updating discord.py to at least [commit `36f039a1bffb835a555be8a43976397ba6eb9c76`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/36f039a1bffb835a555be8a43976397ba6eb9c76), by using `pip install git+https://github.com/rapptz/discord.py` in terminal.

## Outdated Answer

### Explanation

It appears as though there is a bug with discord.py which causes this error. In `_check_can_run` for hybrid commands, it uses `interaction._baton` as the command context to check. `interaction._baton` is set to a missing sentinel value, so it runs into errors when `discord.py` tries to use it like a regular `Context` object.

This can be patched pretty simply, although I'm not sure of any unintended side effects. Simply set `interaction._baton` to be the context you've just fetched. I've tested it with both test cases and they work:

### Code

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="help", guild=discord.Object(id=703732969160048731))
async def help_command(interaction: discord.Interaction, parameter: str = None):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Test")

    cmd = bot.get_command(parameter)

    ctx: commands.Context = await bot.get_context(interaction)

    interaction._baton = ctx  # sketchy, but it works

    try:
        await cmd.can_run(ctx)
        embed.add_field(name="Usable by you:", value="Yes")
    except commands.CommandError as exc:
        embed.add_field(name="Usable by you:", value=f"No:\n{exc}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```